# Find $c$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(a,b) = \mathbb{Q}(c)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a$ be a root of $x^3-x+1$ and $b$ be a root of $x^2-2x-1$. Find $c$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(a,b) = \mathbb{Q}(c)$.

Any hints on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you seen a proof of the primitive element theorem?

Comment: No i have not i looked it up on wikipedia, but the problem i am having is that i can't find the roots of  $x^3 - x +1$. i know it has one real and two complex roots @TokenToucan

Comment: Hint : try to choose $\lambda\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $c=a+\lambda b$ works (you don't need to have a formula for the roots).